# How to incorporate boundary conditions on infinite intervals in numerical methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Let's say we have a second order ordinary differential equation,
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+g(x)y = h(x)
$$
given with some boundary conditions, from which one of them reads:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = a
$$
I want to know how can I incorporate such a condition while numerically solving the equation on a computer? The way I know to solve BVPs on a computer is using shooting method, but I think I can not just "shoot to infinity" in this case.
A solution might be to use a very large positive number in place of infinity and then maybe use shooting method or maybe "integrate backwards" toward origin. I am not very sure how to approach this.

The actual problem I am working on, requires me to find the numerical solutions to Time independent Schrodinger's equation for the case of Hydrogen atom, in particular the Radial part. In the analytical solution, we reject the solutions that blow up at infinity, I think it is in that sense we incorporate the condition that Solution should go to zero as radial distance tends to $\infty$.
But how to do this numerically? If I state my specific problem, It is to solve the following equation:
$$
\frac{d^2u}{d\rho^2}  = \left[1-\frac{\rho_0}{\rho}+\frac{l(l+1)}{\rho^2}\right]u
$$
where $\rho_0$ and $l$ are constants. We don't know that $l$ is quantized as of now, we just know that $\rho$ should tend to zero at $\infty$ and that it's normalized. I want to solve this problem numerically.

Comment: A shooting method works very well. Choose some large r and calculate the value there. If you have any of the growing solution, the magnitude will be huge. The magnitude changes sign when you hit an eigenvalue, so use that to zero in on the solution. Note that due to the singular point at the origin, you may need to shoot backwards as well.

Comment: Look up "far-field solutions" or "singular/infinite boundary elements". In the last example the equation reduces to approximately $u''=u$ at infinity, and rejecting the diverging solutions leads to $u'=-u$ for the remaining admissible solutions. This can then be used as boundary condition at even not so large points. Close to $ρ=0$ you would use the Frobenius power series to cover some initial segment.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you for replying. I have a question, How will I shoot backwards? I mean in forward shooting I know I am 'aiming' for a particular value, that is $e^{-\rho}$ for some large $\rho$. But If I stand on the right side how will I know what to 'aim' at while shooting backwards?

Comment: Youre aiming for a finite value at the origin. The singular point there in the equation means there may be a divergent solution there. Also my experience with ode solvers is that they arent fans of boundary conditions given at singular points. In this case, you'd pick some boundary condition like $u(1)=1$, then vary $u'(1)$ and $l$ until you find one thats finite in both directions.